# Trying to convert .accde back to .accdb

Tags: vba

I made changes to VBA code in .accdb file then debug it and rename it to .accde and sent for testing. Now the testing has been completed successfully and when I again convert it back to .accdb I can't open my code.

Is my code lost now? I don't remember my changes. Is there a way to see my changes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you literally just rename the file extension? If so, renaming it back would be suffice.

But, if you did in fact compile the ACCDB file into ACCDE and threw away the original ACCDB file, then you are in a bad position because ACCDE is basically the ACCDB with all the source code stripped out, and you cannot make any changes without the source code.

All is not lost, though - if you are willing to pay for it, [there's a service that provides the reverse engineering](https://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.asp) provided by everythingaccess.com. I am not aware of free options (and I would be very skeptical of any such thing - reverse engineering is not trivial).

Comment: I only renamed extension. Also I tried renamimg it back to .accdb but not working for me.